# finding bases for row space and null space of matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My problem is:

For the matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
      1&  4&  5&  6&  9\\
      3& −2&  1&  4& −1\\
     −1&  0& −1& −2& −1\\
      2&  3&  5&  7&  8\end{bmatrix}$$

(a) Find a basis for the row space of A.

(b) Find a basis for the null space of A.

(c) Find the rank and nullity of A.

I tried searching online and I became more confused, take the example here.

http://www2.kenyon.edu/Depts/Math/Paquin/PracticeExam1Solns.pdf

As you can see for the column space he takes the columns of the original matrix instead of the rref of A, which I don't understand.

Comment: He uses the columns of the original matrix because elementary row operations change the column space. The column space of ref(A) is not the same as the column space of A (*the two spaces are however isometric*). Doing elementary row operations do not change the row space. ROw space of the row echelon form of A is the same as the row space of A because elementary row operations are linear combinations of the rows.

Comment: Your title is nonsensical. A linear operator is a function, a basis is a set of vectors. Apples and oranges.

Comment: sorry Andres you can suggest a better title if you like.

Comment: "Finding bases for row space and null space of matrix."

Answer (score 10):

We'll begin by simplifying the matrix using elementary row operations.
$$\begin{eqnarray*}A = \begin{bmatrix}
      1&  4&  5&  6&  9\\
      3& −2&  1&  4& −1\\
     −1&  0& −1& −2& −1\\
      2&  3&  5&  7&  8\end{bmatrix}&\xrightarrow{R_4+2R_3}&\begin{bmatrix}
      1&  4&  5&  6&  9\\
      3& −2&  1&  4& −1\\
     −1&  0& −1& −2& −1\\
      0&  3&  3&  3&  6\end{bmatrix}\\
&\xrightarrow{R_3+\frac{1}{3}R_2}&\begin{bmatrix}
      1&  4&  5&  6&  9\\
      3& −2&  1&  4& −1\\
      0& -\frac{2}{3}& -\frac{2}{3}& -\frac{2}{3}& -\frac{4}{3}\\
      0&  3&  3&  3&  6\end{bmatrix}\\
&\xrightarrow{R_2-3R_1}&\begin{bmatrix}
      1&  4&  5&  6&  9\\
      0& −14&  -14&  -14& −28\\
      0& -\frac{2}{3}& -\frac{2}{3}& -\frac{2}{3}& -\frac{4}{3}\\
      0&  3&  3&  3&  6\end{bmatrix}\\
&\xrightarrow{\substack{-(1/14)R_2\\-(3/2)R_3\\(1/3)R_4}}&\begin{bmatrix}
      1&  4&  5&  6&  9\\
      0& 1&  1&  1& 2\\
      0& 1&  1&  1& 2\\
      0& 1&  1&  1& 2\end{bmatrix}\\
&\xrightarrow{\substack{R_4-R_3\\R_3-R_2 \\R_1-3R_2}}&\begin{bmatrix}
      1&  0& 1&  2& 1\\
      0& 1&  1&  1& 2\\
      0& 0&  0&  0& 0\\
      0& 0&  0&  0& 0\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
We see that the row space of $A$ is spanned by $(1,0,1,2,1)$ and $(0,1,1,1,2)$, which means that the rank of $A$ is $2$.  From this, we know by the [Rank-Nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank-nullity_theorem) that the nullity will be $3$, since there are $5$ columns in the matrix - but let's verify that anyway by finding a basis of the null space.  We have the following reduced system of equations.
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
x+z+2s+t&=&0\\
y+z+s+2t&=&0\\
&\downarrow&\\
x&=&-z-2s-t\\
y&=&-z-s-2t\end{eqnarray*}$$
which we can rewrite in vector form as
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
s \\
t \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-z-2s-t \\
-z-s-2t \\
z \\
s \\
t \\
\end{bmatrix}=
z\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\\1 \\0 \\0 \\\end{bmatrix}+
s\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-1\\0 \\1 \\0 \\\end{bmatrix}+
t\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-2\\0 \\0 \\1 \\\end{bmatrix}$$
So a basis of the null space is $(-1,-1,1,0,0)$, $(-2,-1,0,1,0)$, and $(-1,-2,0,0,1)$.

Comment: +1 Nice answer but, I think the last vector in the basis for the null space should be $\begin{pmatrix} -1& -2 & 0& 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^T$

Comment: what about the column space, can you demonstrate that as well please? (Which is what confused me in the other example).

Comment: @BradS. Thanks, that was a copy error.  I corrected it.

Comment: @user3424493 Do you know how to transpose matrices?  Do exactly what I did to find the row space, but for $A^\intercal$.  Let me know what you get.

Comment: @user3424493, the columns of the original matrix which correspond to the pivot columns in the row echelon form of $A$ form a basis for the column space. In this case, columns 1 and 2 of the original matrix form a basis for the column space. There is no need to row reduce $A^T$

Answer (score 0):

The row space is the span of the rows of $A$. (or the column space of $A^{T}$). 
$$
A^{T} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & -1 & 2\\
4 & -2 & 0 & 3 \\
5 & 1 & -1 & 5 \\
6 & 4 & -2 & 7\\
9 & -1 & -1 & 8 \end{bmatrix} \vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \\ 9\end{bmatrix}x_1 + \begin{bmatrix} 3\\ -2 \\ 1 \\ 4 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}x_2  + \begin{bmatrix} -1\\ 0 \\ -1 \\ -2 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}x_3 + \begin{bmatrix} 2\\ 3 \\ 5 \\ 7 \\ 8\end{bmatrix}x_4
$$
So find a maximally linear independent subset $R$ of:
$$
\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \\ 9\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 3\\ -2 \\ 1 \\ 4 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}  , \begin{bmatrix} -1\\ 0 \\ -1 \\ -2 \\ -1\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 2\\ 3 \\ 5 \\ 7 \\ 8\end{bmatrix} \right\}
$$
Now the null space is the set: $$\{\vec{x}: A\vec{x} = \vec{0} \}$$

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
      1&  4&  5&  6&  9\\
      3& −2&  1&  4& −1\\
     −1&  0& −1& −2& −1\\
      2&  3&  5&  7&  8\end{bmatrix}\vec{x} = \vec{0} \longrightarrow \; ?
$$
So you must find a maximally linear independent subset $S$ of
$$\{\vec{x}: A\vec{x} = \vec{0} \}$$ Now once you find these two things,
$$
\text{rank}(A) = |R|,  \; \; \text{nullity}(A)= |S|
$$